# Trying to search email on exchange server with android phone

Tags: email, exchange, search

I have setup a corporate email account on my android phone and it syncs like it should 1 month's worth of email.  When I search for email, it only returns results for the email that is synced on the phone. How can I search the other email that is on the exchange server?

Comment: Which email program are you using?

Comment: The default email program on the phone.